# Must a partial halt decider be a pure function of its inputs?

Tags: computability, c, theory

**Must a partial halt decider be a pure function of its inputs?**

A partial halt decider correctly decides the halt status of some of its inputs.

I am trying to write C code that would be acceptable to computer scientists in the field of the theory of computation.

In computer programming, a pure function is a function that has the following properties:

(1) The function return values are identical for identical arguments (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams).

(2) The function application has no side effects (no mutation of local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input/output streams).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function#Compiler_optimizations

I created a partial halt decider that is able to tell when it is called in infinitely nested simulation. It can only do this if it has a static memory variable to keep track of the simulation of its input across recursive invocations.

**Does this still meet the Halting Problem requirement that the function must be a pure function of its inputs?**

Comment: I wonder if some context is missing here. Require pure functions where and according to what? An actual complex language like C is hard to formalize, but what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Randomized functions do not necessarily return identical values for identical inputs. Implementations of operations on data structures do have side effects on the data structure. Perhaps you should narrow down "theory of computation" when making this kind of statements.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I made a partial halt decider that seems to work in cases where other halt deciders do not work. It requires that I use a single static local variable to hold the ongoing execution trace. I need to know whether or not this use of a static variable makes my work not apply to the halting problem. The function does seem to derive a single unique output for every unique input pair.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus In order for my partial halt decider to be able to determine that it is being called in infinitely nested simulation it must be able to retain the execution trace of its input between recursive simulations of itself. This seems to require a static local variable.

Comment: @Juho Please see my reply to YuvalFilmus for the full context.

Comment: This question seems to be based on a faulty premise.  I don't believe that theory of computation problems  require pure functions.  I'm not sure where you got that idea from.  It's not clear to me what you mean by "theory of computation problems" or what it would mean for them to "require a pure function".  I think you'll need to explain more clearly what you are asking and why you think that such a requirement exists before this will be answerable.  Your comments didn't help me as it's not clear how they are connected to the parts that I don't understand.

Comment: @D.W. I have been told repeatedly that for a partial halt decider to address the halting problem that this partial halt decider must be a pure function of its inputs. Perhaps these people simply lied?

Comment: That's a much different statement than claiming "theory of computation problems require pure functions".  It's very important in this field to be precise about what you are claiming and what you are asking.

Comment: @D.W. I reworded the question, can it be reopened now?

Comment: Next up I think you will need to define "partial halt decider".  That is a phrase I have never heard before, apart from you.

Comment: @D.W. I updated it defining "partial halt decider".

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Please don't change your question after you already receive an answer, as that invalidates the existing answer.  We want to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others.

Comment: @D.W. That was a clarification to my original question.  I only added detail. My research depends on the answer to this more specific question.

Comment: It's a different question.  I think it should be asked separately.  When you have a follow-up question or a new question, please ask it separately in a separate post, rather than editing it to add it to an existing question.  We expect you to think carefully about what exactly your question is and to formulate it accurately, precisely, and thoroughly the first time you ask, so you don't waste the time of answerers.  Also, questions about code are typically off-topic here.

Comment: @D.W. I asked it with increasing levels of specificity because there is a clear history on stack exchange that the more direct questions on the halting problem tend to merely get voted down with hardly any actual review at all. The related issue is that after a few (new question) revisions of the same question I have been barred from asking questions.

Comment: @D.W. I think that it still meets your criteria of "observationally pure". The initial input does always consistently derive the same final output. The only thing that is occurring in-between are simulations.

Comment: You should delete the part of this question where you have claimed to solve the halting problem. You have not solved the halting problem, and your repeated attempts to "prove" that you have solved the problem merely attract downvotes. You can simply ask whether a partial halt decider must be pure. You should also define what a partial halt decider is. Many programs can be said to correctly decides the halt status of *some* of their inputs. In fact I think the only ones that don't are the ones where programs can't be inputs, and the ones where no values are output.

Comment: for example bool f(string p) {return p.charAt(0) == 'm';} correctly decides the halt status of some of its inputs (specifically the ones that start with m and halt, or do not start with m and do not halt)

Comment: @user253751 I specifically need to know whether or not partial halt decider H as described above can use static local variables to determine that is has been called by P in infinitely recursive simulation and such would be Turing computable.

Comment: Please limit your post to one question only. Also, it is unclear to me how your code-snippet is relevant. Note that in general, we advise against writing (pseudo)code in favor of clear but precise descriptions of the algorithm. ... Reading between the lines a bit, I suspect you may be falling in the "trap" of confusing precision with formalism. Arguments made in notation are often precise, but can obscure the situation if the notation is not designed to answer this type of question. So, when in doubt, retreating to precise, English, descriptions of your object can help understanding it.

Comment: @polcott You haven't defined "partial halt decider" in sufficient detail for that question to be answerable. Is it a mathematical function? A C program? A Turing machine? By default the answer for a C program is "no" because C has global variables, for a mathematical function is "yes" because all mathematical functions are pure, and for a Turing machine is "[mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative))" because the concept of a pure Turing  machine has not been defined.

Comment: @Discretelizard I am baffled how anyone sees that the question has changed by simply adding detail or that more than one question has been asked. The code samples are from a fully operational system they are not pseudo-code.

Comment: @user253751 I want to know whether or not the C program that must use static local variables to be able to determine that it has been called in infinitely nested simulation ceases to be Turing computable because it uses static local variables. It does consistently derive the same final output for any initial input.

Comment: @polcott Yes, I'm aware that this is some sort of assembly code. We also recommend against that, in favour of algorithm descriptions in (precise!) English.

Comment: @Discretelizard It is the same question as the one the was initially answered by D.W.  I merely added the key detail that although the initial input always derives the same final output this same input does not derive the same intermediate output. When the function continues to remain in infinitely nested simulation it does not return any value. After it recognizes that it is in infinitely nested simulation it aborts the simulation of this input and returns 0.

Comment: @polcott I think you have misunderstood the argument about pure functions and you solving the halting problem.

Comment: @user253751 I never said anything about solving the halting problem I am only talking about a simulating partial halt decider H correctly deciding the halt status of P. My current solution requires a pair of static local memory variables keeping track of the execution trace of P across recursive simulations of P/H.

Comment: @D.W. I rolled back the question can it be reopened now?

Comment: I am going to leave that up to @Discretelizard.   I note that this post still contains three different questions; normally we prefer that you ask only one question per post.  My answer only attempts to answer one of those three questions.  The post has not yet been rolled back to the state when I wrote my answer below; it contains additional questions not present when I wrote an answer.  As general guidance, we prefer questions that will be useful to others in the future.

Comment: @D.W. I was trying to roll my question back to the one that you approved and got penalized for my attempt to comply. Did I correctly roll back this question to the one that you approved?

Comment: @D.W. Can my question be reopened now that I rolled it back to the point where you approved it?

Comment: @Discretelizard Can the question be reopened now that it has been rolled back to the point where it where it was approved? I was trying to roll it back to this point the first that I rolled it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [decision algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem) is required to behave as an "observationally pure" function.  In other words, its externally observable behavior (for someone who can run it on inputs of their choosing and observe what it outputs) must be consistent with it being a pure function.

Presumably, unless you specify otherwise, any normal reader of your definition of "partial halt decider" would assume that such an algorithm is also required to be observationally pure.

Why?  Because the algorithm is supposed to compute a mathematical function, and a mathematical function is pure, so any algorithm that correctly computes it also must be observationally pure.

There is no requirement that the particular implementation of the algorithm be pure in the sense you have listed.  It is OK to have code that, for instance, defines a local variable and then overwrites its value.  For instance, a Turing machine can overwrite what is written on the tape.  Nonetheless, from the perspective of any external observer who only sees the input-output behavior of the Turing machine, it remains observationally pure.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that I was expecting and it is very helpful. I will paraphrase what you said to test my understanding.

As long as there is one set of inputs such as such as the formal parameters to a function and a single output such as return value of {1,0} (indicating true or false) from this function, then whatever occurs in-between does not make any difference.

Comment: It looks like you may be reiterating the first requirement listed above and saying that we can ignore the second requirement: (Is this correct?) (1) The function return values are identical for identical arguments (no variation with local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference arguments or input streams).

Comment: @polcott That is what D.W. is saying.

Comment: @user253751 so then it is OK to use a pair of static memory variables to keep track of the execution trace of P across recursive simulations of P/H as long as the initial input always derives the same final output.

Comment: @polcott sure but in your "halting problem solver", it doesn't. The same input derives different outputs, or the simulation is not accurate.

Comment: @polcott Note that if your algorithm was "observationally pure", you could write an equivalent version *without* any global or static variables. In particular, the "observationally pure" requirement requires that your algorithm returns the correct answer even if all the global/static variables have their default values when the algorithm begins.

Comment: @user253751 D.W. seemed to define "observationally pure" as having the final output be a pure function of the initial input without regard to anything that occurs in-between.

Comment: @polcott what's the difference between input and initial input, and output and final output? All inputs are initial and all outputs are final. The algorithm can't change the output after the algorithm returns.

Comment: @user253751 The initial input to H(P,P) is the machine address of P, the final output is the integer value of 0. Within the infinitely recursive simulation that is invoked when P calls H(P,P) there are additional inputs yet no outputs. The only output occurs when the outermost H(P,P) aborts the simulation of its input. This is the final output.

Comment: Is a [Pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) also always Turing computable?